# Error when calling allKeys on NSDictionary containg JSON objects

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am working through Apple's sample code for displaying a Twitter feed from here http://bit.ly/x4nhG5

From the example, the code is taking the JSON and putting it into an NSDictionary:

```
        NSDictionary *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

What I was just trying to do at this point was look at all the keys that came back by doing this:

```
NSArray *allKeysArray = [publicTimeline allKeys];
```

I then receive an error while trying to run the program:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray allKeys]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a950f0'

Any reason why this NSDictionary that is loaded from a JSON is behaving this way?

Thanks,
Flea

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the exception you see `'-[__NSCFArray allKeys]`, this indicates that you actually have an `__NSCFArray` which is a private subclass of `NSArray`. This is not an `NSDictionary`, which is why you get the exception.

---

If you look at the JSON feed it is of the form

```
[                             
    {
        coordinates: null,
        truncated: false,
        // ...
    },
    {
        coordinates: null,
        truncated: false,
        // ...
    }
]
```

In [JSON](http://www.json.org/) `[]` represents an array and `{}` represents an object.

> An [JSON] array is an ordered collection of values

This means a JSON array can easily be mapped to an `NSArray`.

> An [JSON] object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

This means a JSON Object can be mapped to an `NSDictionary`.

---

So looking at the feed we can see that we actually have an array of objects. Which `NSJSONSerialization` will turn into an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`'s. Therefore to get to a dictionary we first need to access it from the array first resulting in:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [publicTimeline objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *allKeys    = [tweet allKeys];
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Apple in their code was delcaring *publicTimeLine as a NSDictionary.  In order do use your suggestion; I had to declare *publicTimeLine as an NSArray.

By doing it this way: NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

I was able to use your examples.

Thanks!

Comment: `NSDIctionary may not respond to objectAtIndex` problem occurs. Why?. Am using iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

What the error tells you is that your `publicTimeline` is not `NSDictionary` but `NSArray`.

So, my guess is that instead of

```
NSArray *allKeysArray = [publicTimeline allKeys];
```

this would work as you intend.

```
NSArray *allKeysArray = [[publicTimeline objectAtIndex:0] allKeys];
```

Comment: Barley,  the NSDictionary does not contain a method of objectAtIndex. Would you have another suggestion?